# Grub Bootloader does not detects Windows Bootable USB

Tags: arch-linux, windows, grub, iso, bootable

I have Arch currently installed on my machine. For some reason I want to install Windows 10 (clean install no dual boot). I have a bootable USB made through `dd` command. But everytime I restart and boot from USB, GRUB screen appears and loads Arch linux normally as it previously has. It does not boot the USB so that I can install Windows. Is there a way I can solve this issue?

Comment: Windows does not support the hybrid DVD/flash drive that dd creates with Linux ISO. Best to use a Windows system as the Windows install tools splits the .wim file to fit on a FAT32 partition for UEFI boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274878/make-windows-10-bootable-usb-in-ubuntu Old instructions for creating Windows by just extracting the ISO worked until Windows made .wim file too large. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359706/my-toshiba-laptop-wont-read-my-windows-10-boot-disk/1359829#1359829

Comment: And if you don't have a Windows system around, [woeusb](https://www.fossmint.com/woeusb-create-bootable-windows-usb-sticks-from-linux/) is a tool that can create a Windows installation USB in Linux. There seems to be an [AUR of it for Arch](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/woeusb).

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I used **Ventoy** to make a bootable Windows 10 USB in Arch.